Hiding A Specific Class Using CSS For users and show it to admins only in wordpress
So I'm using this plugin called Mapplic for interactive maps on wordpress
and I'm trying to hide a specific class in it for everyone except admins
so first i added this function to add a class for admin
function add_admin_body_class($classes) {
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        $classes[] = 'is-admin';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'add_admin_body_class');


then i added the CSS code which is
.mapplic-popup-body {
    display: none !important;
}

body.is-admin .mapplic-popup-body {
    display: flex !important;

now it's completely not showing the class for everyone including the admins
could anyone help me out with this please ?
so i tried changing the class in CSS from is-admin to wp-admin and it showed the class in the admin dashboard but i wanna see it in the content itself

Did the class actually get added to the body element?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'admins' - is it anyone who is logged in, or only those who have full administrator capability or...?

How important is it that an ordinary user doesn't see this info, because obviously they can using e.g. their browser devtools using a frontend method.

@C3roe the class did get the body element indeed but
those who have administrator capability , the website is for real estate it's private only for sales and management the hidden class will contain client data which i don't wanna share with my sales team :D

Try simple CSS.
body:not(.is-admin) .mapplic-popup-body{
 display:none;
}

This will hide the container only if admin is not logged in.

i tried it mate , it's hiding the class from the admin dashboard but showing the class to everyone on the content itself

I assume the you want to show the map on the front page templates, instead of the admin dashboard. if having an issue with class not showing at admin dashboard try using admin_body_class filter to add the class in the body.

If you want to hide the class mapplic-popup-body for all users except administrators in WordPress, you can use the following code snippet in your theme's functions.php file:
function hide_class_for_non_admins() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {
        // Output the CSS to hide the specific class
        echo '<style>
            .mapplic-popup-body {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hide_class_for_non_admins');

Feel free to reach out if you have any further questions!
